# Why my Class work properly, Even after returning junk value as return for assignment operator and empty copy constructor?

Tags: c++, assignment-operator, default-copy-constructor

1. I have overridden  default copy constructor and assignment operator with only prints and not returning any thing.
2. How ever, the class works fine i.e., it gets copied and assigned properly.
3. As you can see the **display()** method also gets called properly. (I was expecting crash or segmentation fault as copy constructor and Assignment operator are overridden and doing nothing.
4. I have compiled the same with different compilers including the online one and still output remains the same.

**My Question: 
Why is the class working properly? Without showing any errors? 
I was expecting it to crash or malfunction such as outputting garbage values.**

'

```
class Pizza
{
public:
    Pizza(std::string string) { std::cout << "Ctor :" << string << std::endl; }
    ~Pizza() { std::cout << "Dtor" << std::endl; }

    Pizza(const Pizza& rhs){ std::cout << "Copy Constructor" << std::endl; }
    Pizza& operator=(const Pizza& rhs){ std::cout << "Assignment Operator" << std::endl;}
    void display(){std::cout << "Display method is called on Pizza" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    Pizza pizza = Pizza("1");
    Pizza tizza = pizza;
    tizza = pizza;
    pizza.display();
    tizza.display();
}'
```

The output for the code with g++ (Mingw Compiler) on windows 10 and other compilers too is:

```
Ctor :1
Copy Constructor
Assignment Operator
Display method is called on Pizza
Display method is called on Pizza
Dtor
Dtor
```

Comment: Constructors don't have return values; you say you modified it to "not return anything" - I'm not sure what it looked like before such modification. Your assignment operator exhibits undefined behavior, by way of reaching the end of non-void function without encountering a `return` statement; "seems to work" is one possible manifestation of undefined behavior.

Comment: Exactly thats my point, I have overridden the construct with empty and not returning any thing in assignment operator (assignment operator has return type) in this case it should be junk value. As you see the display method gets called on that object properly. 
I have tried recompiling again and again, to check if I could get any undefined behavior. Every time it worked perfectly.

Comment: *"it should be junk value"* What is "it" in this sentence? Your class doesn't even have any data members that could possibly have values, junk or otherwise. Again, "appears to work every time" is one possible manifestation of undefined behavior.

Comment: How do you determine that what you're observing is *not* junk?

Comment: It refers to the display() method in the class.  I have tried the same code on different compiler including online compilers. Still the output remains same.

Comment: If the values are junk, they should be random on random computers or compilers at-least.

Comment: No they shouldn't, that would be too predictable :)

Comment: @Zaed "If the values are junk, they should be random on random computers or compilers at-least" - why would you think so? Reading uninitialized data is Undefined Behaviour and you can assume *nothing*.

Comment: 1) A constructor can’t return anything – they’re not regular functions; 2) You never use the assignment operator’s non-existent return value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I found the reason:
Thanks to [@Igor Tandetnik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1670129/igor-tandetnik), he had mentioned the same thing in comment on the same day when the question was asked. However since, the comment was brief and I'm still in learning phase, I was unable to get the whole picture from the comment. Hence, decided to write the answer, with a bit of explanation. Which will be helpful for someone like me, Some day :) .

**Reason:**
 - I haven't being using the any data members in the class.
 - I'm only using the class method in the above code. Since, all the objects uses the same class methods (i.e., class methods are per class, not per object.)
 - The main motive of the copy constructor is to copy the data members from one object of the class to another object. 
 - I haven't declared any non-static data member for the class, which are created per object. Declaring non-static members for the above would surely result in undefined behavior of the class. Such data members having garbage values.
-  *Hence, the above code works fine with non-correct copy constructor and move assignment operator.*

Below is the code which will give the garbage values for the data members because of incorrect assignment operator and copy constructor.

```
//g++  5.4.0

#include <iostream>

class Pizza
{
public:
    Pizza(std::string string, int data) : m_string(string), m_data(data) { std::cout << "Ctor :" << string << std::endl; }
    ~Pizza() { std::cout << "Dtor" << std::endl; }
    void set(std::string string, int data) { m_string = string; m_data = data; }
    Pizza(const Pizza& rhs){ std::cout << "Copy Constructor" << std::endl; }
    Pizza& operator=(const Pizza& rhs){ std::cout << "Assignment Operator" << std::endl;}
    void display()
    {
        std::cout << "Display method is called on Pizza" << std::endl; 
        std::cout << "string: " << m_string << " Data: " << m_data << std::endl;
    }

private:
    std::string m_string;
    int m_data;
};

int main()
{
    Pizza pizza = Pizza("Test", 99);
    Pizza tizza = pizza;
    tizza = pizza;
    pizza.display();
    tizza.display();
}
```

**Bottom Line:** Copy constructor, move constructor, assignment operator will make sense the most only when the class has non-static data members.